# How to decode G.729b codec?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am developing an application that listens for RTP data using [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) and converts the received raw data packets using [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).
I works well for codes: PCMA, PCMU, G722 and G729 and converts the received audio files into wav and mp3. But the conversion fails when G729b packet is received. FFMPEG has support for G729 as mentioned [here](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#SEC7) but nothing is mentioned about G729a/b. GStreamer also has not mentioned anything about G729a/b though has a [decoder for G729](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtpg729depay.html). I also didn't find any other library that can convert G729b to wav or mp3. 
Can anyone please suggest any way or any library to convert G729a/b to wav.
Thanks in advance!

Command used: 
ffmpeg  -f g729 -i .g729 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 8000 output.wav

Please find the two files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yw3fz9mzf5hnoxt/sample.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Show your ffmpeg command, the complete log, and provide a sample input file

Comment: I have edited my answer with the command and files. There are two files. One is g729 that is converted correctly and other is g729b which is not converted properly. thanks for replying @LordNeckbeard

Comment: What created the file? Can anything else play it?

Comment: Cisco call manager (CUCM) sends voip call data to recording server. Our app is on the recording server where gstreamer stores the data. For g729 the gsteramer pipeline is: udpsrc port=5008 caps="application/x-rtp,channels=(int)1,media=(string)audio,payload=(int)18,clock-rate=(int)8000,encoding-name=(string)G729" ! rtpg729depay ! filesink

Call is done through cisco IP phones and softphones, which means they can decode and play the codec. Wireshark (from this link https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecodeG729) was not able to decode g729 b codec but it could decode g729.

Comment: I don't know anything about G.729, but consider submitting a feature request to support G.729B on the [FFmpeg Bug Tracker](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/). You will need to provide: 1) a link to a sample file like you did here 2) the actual command you tried 3) the complete log from the command 4) and make sure you're using the most recent ffmpeg you can. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds if you can't compile.

Comment: Thank you @LordNeckbeard! I will submit a request to ffmpeg.

Comment: I saw the feature request. Unfortunately you ignored my suggestions #3 and #4 so the ticket was closed as invalid by another developer. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a recent version (or compile if you prefer), re-run the command using the new version, and provide the complete log from that command. Enter this info in the feature request ticket and it will be re-opened.

Comment: thanks again @LordNeckbeard . I compiled ffmpeg code from git also posted the output logs.